# ffmpeg in Docker not recording the whole screen with Selenium

Tags: docker, selenium, ffmpeg

I am having issues recording Selenium tests in Docker.
I am using Selenium Standalone and ffmpeg.
The problem I am having is with the recording. FFMPEG is not recording my entire screen, only about 70% of it. This means that I am missing a part of the screen on the right side and on the bottom.
I have verified that the whole page is being rendered correctly in full size... it is only the video that is not recording the whole screen.
Can you advise how to modify the staring script to record the whole screen in 1920x1080?
This is my Execute Windows batch command in Jenkins:

```
docker stop %inContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%
docker rm %inContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%
docker stop %inVideoContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%
docker rm %inVideoContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%
docker network rm %inNetworkName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%

docker network create %inNetworkName%%inDockerSeleniumPort%
docker run -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080 -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 --env NO_PROXY="xxxx" --env HTTP_PROXY="xxx" --env HTTPS_PROXY="xxx" -d -p %inDockerSeleniumPort%:4444 -p %inDockerVNCPort%:5900 --net %inNetworkName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% --name %inContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% --shm-size="2g" %inSeleniumImageName%
docker run -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080 -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e FILE_NAME=video%inDockerSeleniumPort%.mp4 -e DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME=selenium%inDockerSeleniumPort% -d --net %inNetworkName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% --name %inVideoContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% -v C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\videos:/videos %inVideoImageName%
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is using different environment variable names for screen width and screen height.

```
video-recorder:
    image: ${VIDEO_RECORDER_IMAGE}
    volumes:
        - ./../videos:/videos
    depends_on:
        - chrome-node
    environment:
        - DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME=chrome-node
        - FILE_NAME=chrome.mp4
        - SE_SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
        - SE_SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080
```

In your case, this should work:

```
docker run -e SE_SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080 -e SE_SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e FILE_NAME=video%inDockerSeleniumPort%.mp4 -e DISPLAY_CONTAINER_NAME=selenium%inDockerSeleniumPort% -d --net %inNetworkName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% --name %inVideoContainerName%%inDockerSeleniumPort% -v C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\videos:/videos %inVideoImageName%
```

source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/Video/Dockerfile#L37